# Class method doesn't return list

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have A class that contains a list of another class and i want to return it to the Main class but for some reason i receive nothing and i am pretty sure i'm filling up the list properly!
Here is my Main class

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Poll currpoll = new Poll();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string[] Input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            Person person = new Person(Input[0], int.Parse(Input[1]));
            currpoll.Add(person);

        }
        currpoll.Order();
        List<Person> final = currpoll.Getlist();
        foreach (var person in final)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person);

        }
    }
```

My "Person Class":

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {

    }
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return this.age; }
        set { this.age = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }
}
```

and my last class containing the list

```
class Poll
{
    private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    public void Add(Person member)
    {
        if (member.Age > 30)
        {
            this.people.Add(member);
        }
    }
    public void Order()
    {
        this.people.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }

    public List<Person> Getlist()
    {
        return this.people;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the input of your program ? I suspect that might the age of the persons are less than 30. If so, they will not be added to the list.

Comment: Attach a debugger and step through the code, stepping into relevant methods and using appropriate breakpoints. Follow along and understand the reasoning of each line of code execute. This ask is “help be debug” and is not a minimal reproduction case.

Comment: Your Order() method does nothing, OrderBy returns a *new* list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't initiate the values of the Person's characteristics.

```
public Person(string name, int age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Note that you could also override ToString() in the Person class in order to get nice output:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Name: " + this.name + ", Age: " + this.Age;
}
```

Use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) for further information.

Answer (score -3):

Probably the problem is here:

```
Person person = new Person(Input[0], int.Parse(Input[1]));
```

perhaps you wanted to do something like this:

```
Person person = new Person(Input[i], int.Parse(Input[i+1]));
```

The input to your program may shine some light on it